# CGPoint stringliteral not allowed anymore in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, enums, literals, cgpoint

In iOS 8.0 I had this enum:

```
enum Direction:CGPoint {
    case Top = "{0, -1}"
    case Right = "{1, 0}"
    case Down = "{0, 1}"
    case Left = "{-1, 0}"

    case TopLeft = "{-1, -1}"
    case TopRight = "{1, -1}"
    case DownLeft = "{-1, 1}"
    case DownRight = "{1, 1}"

    case None = "{0, 0}"
}

extension CGPoint: StringLiteralConvertible {

    public static func convertFromStringLiteral(value: StringLiteralType) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPointFromString(value)
    }

    public static func convertFromExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral(value: StringLiteralType) -> CGPoint {
        return convertFromStringLiteral(value)
    }
}
```

Now this worked exactly the way I wanted, I had to use strings because simply `case Top = CGPoint(x:0,y:1)` does not work.

I use it like this ex:

```
1. var Dir:Direction = .None
2. self.center.AddWithPoint(self.Dir.rawValue.multiply(CGFloat(Speed)))
3. bullet.Dir = .Right
```

Now thats how Ive used the enum before 8.1, but now it is not longer allowed.

Now I get a ton of errors saying things like this:

`.    Type 'CGPoint' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

`.    'String' is not convertible to 'CGPoint'`

So is there any way I can make it work as before? Any answer or suggestion are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol changed and does now require
an *initializer*:

```
protocol StringLiteralConvertible : ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible {
    typealias StringLiteralType
    init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType)
}
```

In addition, it inherits from

```
protocol ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralConvertible : UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible {
    typealias ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType
    init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: ExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteralType)
}
```

which in turn inherits from

```
protocol UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible {
    typealias UnicodeScalarLiteralType
    init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: UnicodeScalarLiteralType)
}
```

So you can implement the protocol as:

```
extension CGPoint: StringLiteralConvertible {

    public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self = CGPointFromString(value)
    }

    public init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self = CGPointFromString(value)
    }

    public init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self = CGPointFromString(value)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
 print(Direction.Top.rawValue)
 // Output: (0.0,-1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks you! I had no idea they changed the literal